# What is the Rate of Reaction of Acetaldehyde Dehydrogenase from Saccharomyces Cerevisiae?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I am working on a biochemistry project, and I need to know some information about reaction rates. What is the Rate of Reaction of Acetaldehyde Dehydrogenase from Saccharomyces Cerevisiae?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Kinetics and Reaction Mechanism of Potassium-Activated Aldehyde Dehydrogenase from Saccharomyces cerevisiae](http://www.biochemj.org/bj/173/0787/1730787.pdf) Biochem. J. (1978) 173, 787-798

The kinetics depend upon the particular substrates and cofactors such as the particular aldehyde, NAD vs NADP, the cation activator (K+ or something else). A thiol is also required.